# Указатель на const в MSVC и GCC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

По какой причине данный код в MSVC работает иначе, нежели в gcc:

```
int const foo = 5; 

int* bar = (int*)&foo;

*bar = 1;

cout << foo;
```

Данный код в MSVC выводит 5, в gcc же 1. При этом в дебагере VS видно, что переменная foo стала 1, но выводится, по какой-то причине 5.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Типичный UB - так что и то, и другое верно :)

Comment: @Harry Тогда все отлично, я и пытался этого добиться, не совсем был уверен, спасибо)

Comment: Причина очевидна. Вы сами сказали компилятору, что `foo` это **константа**. Он знает ее начальное значение и всюду использует его. Однако, если вы напишете `volatile int const foo = 5;`, то заставите его   рассматривать  `foo` как несколько странную (а именно -- изменчивую) константу. Не знаю, как MSVC, а g++ version 7.4.0, выводивший без volatile 5, с этим атрибутом у `foo` выводит текущее значение в памяти -- 1.